# Select Price value only from td in python

Tags: python, html, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to capture just price value from html td tag but the problem is there are other td with same class name: please see the picture below. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV6BK.jpg)

here is the code i have written

```
from  builtins import any as b_any
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from collections import Counter
import urllib.request
import csv
import schedule
import time
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="http://offer.ebay.es/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewBidsLogin&item=122713288532&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2564"

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

htmlpage = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

html = htmlpage.read().decode('utf-8')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

table = soup.find_all('td',{'class':'onheadNav'})

'''for txt in table:
    nametxt = txt.text
    result = ''.join([i for i in nametxt if not i.isdigit()])
    cleantxt = result.replace('(','')
    print(cleantxt.replace(')',''))

    rank = txt.a.text
    print(rank)'''
price = soup.select('td.contentValueFont')
for pr in price:
    print(pr.text)
```

If i slice price in for loop it will get only first price but i want to have all prices at once.

Edited description:
I want to capture all prices but problem is there are three td with same class name one td is for price one for Cantidad(quantity) and the one which is for date these all have same class. and when i try to get only price section my code returns all three td's. I hope you get it now

Comment: contradiction in your description: **to capture just price value** <-> **i want to have all values at once**. Update your question

Comment: I want to capture all prices but problem is there are three td with same class name one td is for price one for Cantidad(quantity) and the one which is for date these all have same class. and when i try to get only price section my code returns all three td's. I hope you get it now.

Comment: I don't know beautifulsoup much but you may try to get your td by position (for example `td[1]`) instead of getting it by class.

Comment: I sliced it like you are asking but it only return first price and break the loop. it don't go in next iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lazy way:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

table = soup.find_all('table')

trs = table[9].select('tr') # You should select the table first (use your way)

for tr in trs: # loop the tr in the table
    if len(tr.select('td')) > 2: # check length
        print(tr.select('td')[2].text) # select third td
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is find all the 'tr' tags in the table you want scraped and then iterate over all those to get the text from the particular 'td'.

Something like this:

```
table = soup.find_all('table')
for tr in table[9].find_all('tr')[1:-1]:
    price = tr.find_all('td')[2].text.strip()
    print(price)
```

After some research we can find out that the table we want is the 10th table on the page, hence `table[9]`. Also, since we don't want the first and the last 'tr' we do `find_all('tr')[1:-1]`

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Short solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://offer.ebay.es/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewBidsLogin&item=122713288532&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2564"
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

prices =[ price.string.replace('\xa0', ' ')
          for price in soup.select('td.contentValueFont') if price.string.endswith('EUR')]
print(prices)
```

The output:

```
['4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '8,90 EUR', '8,90 EUR', '8,90 EUR', '8,90 EUR', '8,90 EUR', '8,90 EUR', '8,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '14,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR', '4,90 EUR']
```